# How to use phan/phan for backwards compatibility (PHP 5.6 -> 7.2)

Tags: compatibility, static-analysis, php-5.6, php-7.2

I'm planning to move my PHP project from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2. I wanted to use [`phan\phan`](https://github.com/phan/phan/) to that end but it checks every programming mistakes under the sun.

Could someone show me how to just run the `backward_compatibility_checks` filter (or suggest some other actively maintained/non-deprecated tools to do this)

Thanks in advance